# How to evaluate quality of signal?

Tags: signal, wireless, snr

guys. I'm trying to evalute received signals from a transceiver. I'm a rookie in wireless communication. So I hope that you guys can help me out. I want to make a threshold of received signal so that we can say some signals are meaningless. I have learnt something about Signal-to-Noise-Ratio (SNR) and Reveived-Signal-Strength (RSS). But I found that symbols can still be decoded even in low SNR (<= 0dB).

Here are my questions:

1. If I choose SNR as my metrics, will my threshold be relavant to modulation or coding schemes?
2. Will RSS be suitable for theoritic analysis as metrics?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to go down a path that most simple radio data receivers don't do?

Comment: You can also stop calling everyone "guys" anytime you like. I know I wouldn't be offended if you just asked your question directly.

Comment: @Andy aka I'm doing a radio toy so that I can learn something about wireless communication.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev I'm new here. Thanks for your tips : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad subject.

What matters in a receiver is how well the signal is actually recovered, and that is directly impacted by the [signal to noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) ratio.

There are many sources of noise and [fading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading) and the first one (that we cannot get rid of) is thermal or [Johnson-Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) noise.

This is defined as \$ P = kTB\$ where P is the power in Watts, k = [Boltzmann's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) (\$1.38 \cdot 10^{-23}\$) T is the [thermodynamic temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature) in Kelvin and B the bandwidth of the signal in Hertz.

Then the sensitivity of a receiver (without using special techniques that I will touch on) is at a power level of thermal noise plus the [noise figure](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/noise-figure) of the receiver circuitry.

The higher the signal to noise ratio, the lower the [bit error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate) (for digital signalling) or the less noisy the analogue signal is (for an analogue domain). Note that although a signal may appear to be crystal clear, some noise till exists; you just cannot hear it. This noise level applies for any specific given type of [modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation).

Different forms of modulation have different [channel capacities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity) vs Signal to noise ratio.

There are many types of [signal encoding](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~kannan/cse3461-5461/Cse3461.C.SignalEncoding.09-04-2012.pdf).

There are methods of recovering signals that are below the noise floor by using averaging techniques; if a signal with a relatively narrow band is continuously present, and the frequency range of interest is accumulated over time, it will rise above the noise (which is broadband and flat).

[GPS](http://www.gpssource.com/faqs/15) is one such example of this.

Hopefully, this very broad brush look shows why there is significant knowledge required to determine the best metric for a given signal link.

Comment: So, a more specific answer to my question will be some speaking from experience. I will appreciate it if you can give me some guidebooks or more concrete clues